# USB file transfer from Linux Mint 18.1 to Android 6 device

Tags: linux, usb, linux-mint, android

This works fine to the Android tablet's internal storage, but not to the tablet's SD card.

The error message is "**libmtp error: Could not send object.**"

Comment: Does it work with Windows? I have seen this before where the media and storage databases just need to be cleared and rebuilt, if it is the same regardless of OS, probably that, if it's only your Linux box, then try the answer below.

Answer (score 4):

I found installing the below on Mint 19 and rebooting both devices helps immensely

```
sudo apt install mtp-tools android-tools-adb
```

If the device is a usb3 typeC or similar you might also want to try using a slower usb2 port. This seems to help keep it from trying to write to the internal storage so fast it crashes right away and then reconnects.

Comment: I try on Linux Mint 19, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It could be because your tablet is not supported by the libmtp version you have installed.

1. Connect the tablet to your computer the use 'mtp-detect' in the terminal to get version number & some info about your tablet. Here is the result for mine

   ```
   user@X ~ $ mtp-detect
   libmtp version: 1.1.10

   Listing raw device(s)
   Device 0 (VID=XXXX and PID=YYYY) is UNKNOWN in libmtp v1.1.10.
   Please report this VID/PID and the device model to the libmtp development team
   ```

   As you can see my device is currently not supported by libmtp v1.1.10 so I need to install the latest version
2. get the latest version from https://sourceforge.net/projects/libmtp/files/libmtp/
3. extract, build, install